Use of container_of() macro for pointer as structure elements
If I have a struct defined like this:
struct a {
  int b;
  char *c;
};

struct d {
  struct a *_a;
  int e;
};   

Then assuming elsewhere in the code I have a pointer to a, can I retrieve pointer to d like this?
int do something (struct a *p)
{
    struct d *_d = container_of(p, struct d, _a);

    _d->e = 0x232;
    ...
}

When I tried this - I get a compilation error:
./include/linux/compiler.h:358:38: error: call to ‘__compiletime_assert_1276’ declared with attribute error: pointer type mismatch in container_of()
  _compiletime_assert(condition, msg, __compiletime_assert_, __LINE__)


container_of accepts pointer-to-field. It won't work with the value of the field, even if that value is a pointer.

Tsyvarev: I just saw your post ,

changing the first arg to a double pointer fixed my problem :)
